# How can i sign in with different TFS accounts with multiple Visual Studio 2013 instances

Tags: visual-studio

i want to use multiple instances of visual studio 2013 every instance with a TFS user, can i do this ?

Comment: Same TFS server or different ones? On premises or VS Online?

Comment: same TFS server, local VS not online

Answer (score 0):

To enable to connect to TFS with different user accounts in multiple VS instances, please:

1. Do not save any Windows Credentials to connect to TFS in Credential Manager
2. Log in computer with a user account which doesn't have permission to access TFS

Then when you try to connect to TFS server in VS, you will get a  Windows Security dialog which asks for username and password which is used to connect to TFS server. Like:

[image]

Take **note** that, please do not select the **Remember my credentials** checkbox to avoid saving Windows Credential in Credential Manager. And if you open another VS instance, you will be prompted with the same dialog again, and you can now connect with another different user account.

By the way, any reason why you would like to connect with different user accounts on the same machine?